# User.insertMany is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux, react-redux

this is the code

```
import express from 'express';
import User from './Models/UserModel.js';
import users from './data/users.js';

const ImportData = express.Router();

ImportData.post('/user', async (req, res) => {
  await User.remove({});
  const importUser = await User.insertMany(users);
  res.send({ importUser });
});

export default ImportData;
```

and im getting this error

```
const importUser = await User.insertMany(users);
                                ^  

TypeError: User.insertMany is not a function
```

I'm a beginner so I don't really know how to fix it

Comment: this means `insertMany` does not exist on `User`

Comment: Can you share the `UserModel.js` code?